# What does "Cch" mean in StringCchPrint*?

Tags: visual-c++

`fprintf` means "[f]ile [print] [f]ormatted".

For the StringCchPrint`*` family (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchprintfa), I can't find anything mentioning [Cch].

I know that the `A` suffix denotes `char`, the `f` suffix denotes TCHAR (text char? which appears to be what they want the deafult data type to be for this type of stuff?) and `W` denotes WCHAR (wide char?)

I have no experience with windows naming conventions, this is confusing.

Comment: "the f suffix denotes TCHAR " the `f` is not a suffix it is part of the standard function name `printf` which it is related to.  Thus you have `StringCchPrintfW` not `StringCchPrintW`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (lowercase) "ch" part of the names refers to the fact that these functions take a count of ***characters*** as their relevant argument(s), as opposed to the related functions with a "b" in their names (such as `StringCbPrintf`), which take a count of ***bytes***. (These counts are different when using `UNICODE` builds, where the strings are formed of 2-byte `wchar_t` elements.)

Further, as pointed out by [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv), the uppercase "C" [stands for "count"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/strsafe-ovw) - which is similar to the Microsoft naming convention for structure members that are 'counts', such as `.cbSize` or `.cchLength`.

Comment: The "C" actually [stands for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/strsafe-ovw) "count": "*each function is available in a corresponding character count ("cch") or byte count ("cb") version*".

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for finding that reference! I hope you don't mind me incorporating your comment into my answer.

Comment: Not at all, it's a good answer to a good question, which I +1'd both.